# UIView overlapping Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

In a viewController I programmatically create a UIView that has the same height of the screen. The problem is that navigation bar is still visible and clickable, but I want it to go under the new view. How can I do that?

EDIT: this is a screenshot of what I have now

[image]

Comment: Ok. So, do you have an example of how you want it to look? You want it in a different color, or ...?

Comment: I want the "item" button to disappear and the "back" button not to be tappable (the grey view is semi-transparent so the back button is still visible)

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm a little bit confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you actually want, since hiding it is a quite acceptable thing to do. However you can hide the `rightButtonItem` and disable the left one:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

And to get back your right bar button, if you need it again somewhere:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.*whatever*ButtonItem;
```

See if that works. I'm away from my Mac at the moment, so can't check it myself.

Comment: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem doesn't have a "hidden" property.

Comment: Now it works, but setting it to nil means that I have to create it again when I close the side menu (ok, I didn't see your edit). At this point I think that hiding the whole navigation bar is a better solution. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Yeah, I agree that this approach is a little bit messy. Also, please "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark next to each answer.

Comment: I'll wait just a little more time (maybe someone has a great idea), then I'm going to accept your answer.

Comment: Ah, sure. (:
Btw, something else is coming to my mind, but again, I'd like to try it myself before suggesting it. 
If you're using storyboards/NIBs, can you try dragging the navigation controller below the view that you want to be on top? I've spent loads of time messing around with navigation controllers, and I remember doing those stuff a while back, but I'm not sure if that'll actually work.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, but I will try (yes, I'm using storyboards and nibs).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55834/discussion-between-neeku-and-heisenberg).

Answer (score 0):

> Right now you have taken navigation controller as a root view
>   controller (Maybe),In this case navigation controller overlaps the
>   UIVewController's view that's why it comes on the view so you need to
>   hide the Navigation controller.

Answer (score -1):

What about making it hidden?

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

Comment: I know it's the easiest solution, but I prefer to keep it visible because the view doesn't cover all the width of the screen (I'm implementing a kind of side menu).

Comment: @Heisenberg How about providing a screenshot?